# Practice of saving a singleton instance of an angular-service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

When I first learned about the `angular-redux` library, I think the most inviting part of the library was the `@select` decorator, which meant I wouldn't have to inject the `store service` every time I want to select from the store.

It made me wonder - how does the decorator get access to that service?
I researched the source code, and stumbled upon the [@select](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/src/decorators/select.ts) and [NgRedux (the store service)](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/src/components/root-store.ts) code.

Apparently, a `static instance` of the service is saved when the service is initialized, and the `decorator` accesses this instance.

I wanted to know how acceptable this practice is, since I've liked the idea and I've used it myself to create `decorators` and `rxjs operators` for my services, but the idea of saving a singleton is still rather peculiar for me, it feels like a weird hack.

Again, I would love your opinion of how acceptable this practice is, and whether there is a way to use `Angular`'s `Dependency Injection` to avoid this.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Services that are defined in NgModules are lazy singletons by definition. It means that if you are not going to override service using `providers` section of component, then you are safe to save references to the service instance.

Main disadvantage is testability problems, it this case you have to pay this price for convenient usage.

Comment: My problem resides not in components, directives, pipes, or services, which are all `@Injectable`. My problem is with things that aren't part of angular - such as `decorators`, and `rxjs operators`, which people use to customize their code. I know that this method works, it does wonders in my code, but I hoped there would be a more `DI`-y way of doing this.

Comment: Angular's DI does not provide any capabilities similar to proxies or interceptors and it does not support property injection, so it is impossible to get injector reference or service without passing it through constructor. It means that you will have to use factory for your service to be able to use decorators and do some plumbing for each service which uses decorators. The only clean way to use services in custom rxjs operators is to pass them directly as parameters. So it is compromise between clean design and convenience of use.